# Electron google api uri

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, google-calendar-api

im doing a desktop app with react and electron
everything works good on the browser when te localhost:3000 is online
but when i export the app to electron the google windows shows the error 400 invalid request [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOaXg.png)

i'm using https://github.com/Kubessandra/react-google-calendar-api this one for the conection

```
const electron = require("electron");
const { webFrame } = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
app.on("ready", () => {


    const display = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay()
    const maxiSize = display.workAreaSize
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({

        resizable: false,
        height: maxiSize.height,
        width: maxiSize.width,

        // autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            zoomFactor: 0.7,

        },
    });
    const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../build/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    });
    mainWindow.on('close', function () {

    })
    mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);

});
```